# ASIHTTPRequest doesn't have authentication info and doesn't ask for it

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to make iPhone app talk to my rails server. (I know I probably shouldn't have used ASIHTTPRequest, but I'm pretty invested in it now, and it works most of the time).

When the app launches, I send a request to the server asking for a JSON file. I'm counting on ASIHTTPRequest to check to see if it has previously stored login credentials and use those. If it doesn't, the request's delegate implements authenticationNeededForRequest: which presents my own custom login dialog.

When the request doesn't have previously stored credentials, the server sends a 401 response. The problem is that inside ASIHTTPRequest, once it sees the 401 response, it logs:

```
[AUTH] Request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x2031a800> received 401 challenge and must authenticate using (null)
```

which is the result of...

```
ASI_DEBUG_LOG(@"[AUTH] Request %@ received 401 challenge and must authenticate using %@%@",self,[self authenticationScheme],realm);
```

So basically, there is no realm and the authentication scheme is null. The request gives up and fails right away, without ever trying any of the other means of obtaining authentication.

I'm launching the request like this in my main view:

```
/* When using a storyboard, this method gets called instead of the old initWithNibName:bundle:. */
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver/file.json"];
        [ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultTimeOutSeconds:20];
        request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        hasConnected = NO;

        newPicturesPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

and ...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  /* We will try to access the server, if we don't have authentication,
   * we'll present the login view. */
   [request setAuthenticationScheme:(NSString*)kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic];
   [request startAsynchronous];
   ...
}
```

Any suggestions as to how I can implement the behavior I want and only present a login screen if we don't have previously saved username/password (and also save the username/password for later)?

EDIT: I'm basing my logic on [this](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIHTTPRequest-AuthenticationProcess.pdf), but it seems that's not how ASIHTTPRequest actually behaves.

Comment: Best advice. Don't use ASIHTTPRequest, use HTTPURLHandler

Comment: even better, use `NSURLConnection`.  There is no reason to use these wrappers. **NOTE:** `ASIHTTPRequest` has been deprecated for over a year.

Comment: I'm out of my areas of expertise on this question, so I may be way off track, but, from the ASIHTTPRequest source and that flowchart, the core issue looks to be the distinction between "can send authentication beforehand" or not. Since you control the server, can you/have you try(ed) changing this behavior on that end to make ASIHTTPRequest happy?

Comment: You make it present the credentials beforehand by setting the authentication scheme, which I've already tried. But that still wouldn't solve the problem for when there is no previously stored authentication info.

Comment: I went through the ASIHTTPRequest code, and it looked like its actual behaviour was not as promised in the flowchart. When it gets challenged for authentication, it only asks the delegate for that info IF it received a "bad username" or "bad password" error: `if (err.domain == kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP && (err.error == kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationBadUserName || err.error == kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationBadPassword))`

I don't know where these errors come from (perhaps the server is responsible?). For now, I've solved my problem by commenting out the second condition.